# How can I hide API secret key when sending AJAX requests?

Tags: ajax, api, security

I am about to start working on a project, which is basically a web interface for a mobile banking application. The API is ready, I only need to provide the frontend part of the web application. I was going to make it using Backbone/Angular/Ember, but started to worry about the security.

Particularly, the following. As a rule, every API request must contain a parameter `method_code`, which is calculated as hash of user token, method name and secret API key. If I put the logic of how this param is calculated into one of .js files, anyone could potentially access some sensitive data using tools like Postman or even browser console. How should I go about this issue? I could have a server-side script generating the `method_code` for me, but is it possible to make it accessible only to my web app's requests?

Comment: I'd say the API server it is not done properly (or you don't use it correctly). Think Google API: it's usually bind to a certain domain, so either if the API key is „stolen”, it cannot be reused.

Comment: @IonutStaicu So basically if I ask the team to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `http://my-web-app.com/`, I should be fine? Or this is not safe?

Comment: You should sign the requests on server side and after that send them with the signature via ajax. Afaik. oauth does something like this. I suggest you to use an existing solution instead of reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> every API request must contain a parameter method_code, which is calculated as hash of user token, method name and secret API key
>
> I could have a server-side script generating the method_code for me, but is it possible to make it accessible only to my web app's requests?

Yes, the server-side script would be the way to go if you do not want to expose the secret API key within your client side code or request data.

User token can (presumably) come from the user's session cookie value? So simply have a server side method that takes the `method name` and then returns the `method_code` calculated from the `secret API key` (kept server side only) and the `user token`.

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) will prevent another domain making a request to your API and retreiving the `method_code`. I'm also assuming the API and front-end code runs on the same domain here, although if this is not the case you can use [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) to allow your front-end code to read and retreive data client-side via the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate a token based on security factors and encrypt that and use it in your requests to identify your clients and valid requests.